# Threads in GUI (Swing) - application unfreeze

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, swing

I have a question regarding threads in Java Swing Application. There's a module in my app which receives and sends email messages. I'd like to assign an action to a Button (mouseClicked) to receive unread emails.

Pseudo-code:

```
ExchangeConnector ec = new ExchangeConnector();
ArrayList<Mail> unreadMails = ec.receive(Mail.UNREAD);
// (...)
ec.close();
```

My current implementation makes application freeze, until receiving is complete (sometimes it could take more than 10 minutes).

The question is - how to make it completely "in background", making my application usable for other actions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [SwingWorker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SwingWorker) for doing this kind of thing off the Swing Thread.

SwingWorker is:

> useful when a time-consuming task has to be performed following a user-interaction event

Answer (score 2):

Johan Sjöberg gave the hint: put the long-running task into a thread. I further want to add: don't start different threads (unless you really need to do), but instead use one dedicated worker thread for such operations. Otherwise you will get lost in thread-nirvana. Keeping an eye on two threads (event dispatch thread and worker thread) is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of blocking the swing thread, create a new thread to perform the receive for you. E.g.,

```
new Thread(new EmailReceiver(new ExchangeConnector())).start();
```

And the EmailReceiver

```
public class EmailReceiver implements Runnable {
     private ExchangeConnnector ec;

     public EmailReceiver(ExchangeConnector ec) {
         this.ec = ec;
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {
         ec.receive(Mail.UNREAD);
     }
}
```

Comment: Well this is highly discouraged, and @mklhmnn explained why :).

Comment: @FearUs, Obviously this was mean to illstrate how to perform tasks in the background, not a complete program with thread management, event dispatch etc.